# How to compare the string with case insensitive

Tags: python, python-2.7

I already know about the lower() and upper() but is there any simplest method to do it,for example like ignoreCase() in Java,

ex code: 
a="hello how are you,i am praveen",

now if i do   "PRAVEEN" in a:

it gives us false,i want to make it caseinsensitive
   thank you in advance

Comment: What list? please create an [mcve].

Comment: now see the example what i given and please help me

Comment: Have you tried copying your question title into google?...

Comment: ya,but it showing only lower() and upper() so i am here

Comment: This task is only simple if the strings are plain ASCII (or Latin1). If you need to handle arbitrary Unicode then you need to be careful, as the top answers at the suggested duplicate question show. FWIW, the `re` module can do case-insensitive comparisons & searches using the `re.IGNORECASE` flag, but it's not safe to use on arbitrary Unicode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be missing something but I think the simplest solution is just to use the `lower()` function.

```
s = "PRAVEEN"
a = "hello how are you,i am praveen"

# will return true if s in a (regardless of original upper/lower cases)
if s.lower() in a.lower():
    print "s in a"
```

You could write a function for it if you have to do it many times?

```
def isInString(substring, originalString):
    if substring.lower() in originalString.lower():
        return true
    else:
        return false
```

Comment: Ok thank you, but  if the string  is dynamic then how we can perform

Comment: @praveenJP happy to help! :) what do you mean by dynamic?

Comment: thank you @RichSmith, i got it